# C++ How to use stand-alone base object from derived object

Tags: c++, inheritance, derived-class

I have 3 classes. One is a base, one is a parent and one is a child. The parent is instantiated at some point and assigned data. In some cases it is used directly but in others there is a need for functionality implemented in its child class.

What I would like to do is to cast the parent object into child object so its virtual functions would be used with parent's data:

```
class UndoBase : public QUndoCommand
{
public:
    UndoBase() {}    

    virtual void undo() = 0;
    virtual void redo() = 0;
};

class CommandParent : public UndoBase
{
public:
    CommandParent() {}

    virtual void undo()
    virtual void redo()

protected:
    someType data
};

class CommandChild : public CommandParent
{
public:
    CommandChild() {}

    virtual void undo() //overrides parent
    virtual void redo() //overrides parent
};
```

I have tried this:

```
CommandParent *parent = new CommandParent;
//assign data
UndoBase *command = static_cast<CommandChild*>(parent);
command->redo();
```

And it worked (used the CommandChild implementation and CommandParent data) although I would swear it should be undefined behaviour (that could work too, I know). Since I doubt this is the right thing to do I would like to ask if this is ok or if there is other ways beside composition.

Comment: if you create your object as a parent, it can never become/transform into a child. You have to instanciate it as a child, treat it as a parent, and sometimes treat it as a child.

Comment: `ommandParent *parent = new CommandParent;`, Any consideration *at all* of `CommandChild` after this line is wrong. No such object exists, and you don't magically create one by waving a casting-wand.

Comment: Yes I get that. Any way of "injecting" the base object into the child as its base?

Comment: @Resurrection no standard one AFAIK. You'd better off changing something in your design

Comment: What ? The "base object", `UndoBase` already *is* in the inheritance hierarchy of `CommandChild`. What is the *real* problem you're trying to solve? Invoking some member, ex: `CommandParent::redo()`, directly from a `CommandChild` object pointer/reference rather than biting into the virtual override apple?

Comment: From the child point of view, you may call parent virtual methods (`parent::virtualMethod()`) and from the parent, if you call a virtual function implemented in child, that's the child implementation that will be called.

Comment: @WhozCraig I have a model class that issues commands for the undo stack. That model class creates a command and hands it to virtual processing function. In a sub-class of that model I intercept the command in the overridden processing function and I want to make it into the child command (appropriate to model sub-class whereas the base model uses parent command). This is for ease of use because otherwise I would have to override all functions that issue commands and/or copy the data twice.

Comment: @Resurrection unless the actual *object* you're intercepting is, in fact a `CommandChild` or *further* derivative thereof, casting as one is wrong. There is no escaping that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UndoBase *command = static_cast<CommandChild*>(parent);
```

This is all hell at every inch of this line. You are telling to static_cast to cast to CommandChild whereas you are storing it in UndoBase .

Also you are trying to cast CommandParent  to CommandChild means Base to Derived where Base class has no knowledge of derived cast. Even if you write it properly.

```
CommandChild  *child = static_cast<CommandChild*>(parent);
```

it would be erroneous.Apart from that always use dynamic_cast for these cases. It explicitly checks whether cast is possible or not.dynamic_cast will cast properly if cast is safe OR returns NULL (in case of pointers, for references it throws bad_cast exception ) if its not able to cast to target type.

Answer (score -1):

You have to create an new instance of CommandChild with the data from CommandParent using the copy constructor.

```
UndoBase *command = new CommandChild(*parent);
```